# Pandas convert date format

Tags: date, datetime, pandas

My current date column is in the format YYYY-MM-DD but I need it in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
>>> df['Year_Month_Day'].head()
0   2014-09-17
1   2014-09-17
2   2014-09-07
3   2014-09-14
4   2014-09-17
Name: Year_Month_Day, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I tried to use pd.to_datetime to do this:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Year_Month_Day'])
0    2014-09-17
1    2014-09-17
2    2014-09-07
3    2014-09-14
4    2014-09-17
```

But no luck..

Comment: What do you mean no luck? Did you get error messages? An exception? Bad results? Describe your results.

Comment: The results came back as YYYY-MM-DD with no HH:MM:SS

Comment: That is just the way it is printed. If `HH:MM:SS` is all zero, it will not be shown. Do `df['Year_month_day'].iloc[0]` to see that it is actually there.